# How do you prevent Gmail from locking you out of your account when travelling?

Tags: gmail

A relative of mine is currently in a different country and asked me for help as they can't log into their own Gmail account from there. Gmail considers the login attempt suspicious, almost certainly because of the location, and blocks it.

I'm at a non-suspicious location and can still access the account and I can see that Google sent a mail about the suspicious attempt and displays a notification bar warning about it. What I can't see is any way to tell Google that it shouldn't block logins from that location.

How can I prevent Gmail from locking me out like this in a different country? Is there a way to notify it of upcoming trips so that it doesn't consider it suspicious? And is there any way to unlock Gmail once you're in a country it considers suspicious, or do you have to wait until you're home again?

Comment: Consider using 2 step authentication. That way, if Google does not recognize the computer, or IP the account is accessed from, you still have a chance to confirm it's you by providing the second step.

Answer (score 2):

## Before you leave

As Traveling Tech Guy suggests, then best solution is to activating 2 step authentication in [the security settings for the Google account](https://www.google.com/settings/security). Google will now send you a new code each time you log in from a new location.

If you are going to be traveling without roaming activated (or for some other reason wont be able to receive an SMS), you can download and configure Googles Authenticator app: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447

Just to be sure, your should also download a list of [backup codes](https://accounts.google.com/SmsAuthConfig). Each backup code can only be used once, so remember to renew them before you run out. Here's Googles instructions on backup codes: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1187538?hl=en

## When you've already left

It's hard to set up 2 step authentication when you've already left. According to Google, you should be able to verify your account by resetting your password: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2506340?hl=en

If you're unable to reset your password, you should still be able to regain access to your account if you manage to collaborate with someone you trust to set up 2 step authentication for you and have them send you your backup codes.

Answer (score -1):

Using this form should help if you have already traveled to your destination.

https://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/request.py?ara=1&hl=en&contact_type=ara&ctx=ara